# Doubly linked list not printing values properly

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

When I call the methods to print the data stored in the nodes of my doubly linked list, nothing prints except for empty strings and 0's

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int weight;
    string name;
    node *nextname, *nextweight;
};
node *namehead = NULL, *weighthead = NULL;

bool isEmpty()
{
    if (namehead == NULL && weighthead == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void addperson(int w, string n)
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    node *prev, *curr = newNode;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        namehead = newNode;
        weighthead = newNode;
    }
    else {
        curr = prev = namehead;
        if (curr->name > n) {
            namehead = newNode;
            newNode->nextname = curr;
        }
        else {
            do {
                if (curr->name <= n) {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->nextname;
                }
                else
                    break;
            } while (curr != NULL);
            prev->nextname = newNode;
            newNode->nextname = curr;
        }
        curr = prev = weighthead;
        if (curr->weight > w) {
            weighthead = newNode;
            newNode->nextweight = curr;
        }
        else {
            do {
                if (curr->weight <= w) {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->nextweight;
                }
                else
                    break;
            } while (curr != NULL);
            prev->nextweight = newNode;
            newNode->nextweight = curr;
        }
    }
}

void printname()
{
    node* curr = namehead;
    do {
        cout << curr->name << " - " << curr->weight << endl;
        curr = curr->nextname;
    } while (curr != NULL);
    cout << endl;
}

void printweight()
{
    node* curr = weighthead;
    do {
        cout << curr->name << " - " << curr->weight << endl;
        curr = curr->nextweight;
    } while (curr != NULL);
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int w = 0;
    string n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        cout << "Enter weight: ";
        cin >> w;
        if (w == -1)
            break;
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin >> n;
        addperson(w, n);
    }
    printname();
    printweight();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output (By name):

John - 220

Steven - 190

Tyler - 150

Expected output (By weight):

Tyler - 150

Steven - 190

John - 220

CURRENT OUTPUT(Both ways):

" " - 0

" " - 0

" " - 0

**EDIT**
By taking the suggestions in the comments about actually assigning the values w (weight) and n (name) to the temporary node in the add method, the problem has been fixed. Thank you for the help.

```
curr->weight=w;
curr->name=n;
```

Comment: in `void addperson(int w, string n)` you have `node *newNode = new node;` then `node *prev, *curr = new node;` Why are you allocating 2 nodes for a single person? If the list is not empty the following line leaks the node allocated for curr: `curr=prev=namehead;`

Comment: Try implementing a linked list of `int`, before you attempt a linked list of a more complex data type.

Comment: Where do you set the weight value of the node to the weight value passed as a parameter in `add()`? Could be part of it.

Comment: @Chipster pointed out the second bug. You forgot to set the `weight` and `name` of you new node.

Comment: Ok I've gotten it to print now by assigning the passed values into the weight and name members of the node by doing: `curr->weight = w` and `curr->name = n` and it has printed

Comment: @drescherjm I updated the code so i have `node *newNode = new node;` then I reassigned `node *prev, *curr = new node;` to be `node *prev, *curr = newNode;` But youre right it is causing leaks so I'll fix that.

Comment: The indentation in addPerson is extremely confusing

Answer (score 1):

Assign passed values into weight and name members into placeholder node in the add method:

```
curr->weight=w;
curr->name=n;
```